# remove advertising on login page of Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, single-sign-on, login

I have SSO set up and it looks great.  However, I get a number of "ads" on the right hand side of the login page.  Is it possible to remove those adds without visualforce.  I like the way the current login page functions and looks.  Otherwise, I could create a VF page assuming that it looks and functions the same way.

Also, this is the DIV tag that contains the marketing materials:

```
    <div id="right"><iframe frameborder="0" src="https://c.salesforce.com/login-messages/promos.html" 
    id="marketing" name="marketing" scrolling="no" title="Marketing" tabindex="-1" 
    sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups 
    allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe></div>
```

see attached
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have SSO then I assume you have My Domain enabled.

In the My Domain setup you can set the right frame URL, if it's blank it loads the ad from Salesforce. I would point it to some internal page for your users.

Or, you can create a force.com site page with any image/value you want and it would be 100% on the platform.

Or, I found there are blank website on the internet you could point to as well.

A quick google search found https://blank.org/ which is just a blank white page. In one of my sandboxes I set it and it's a white frame on the login page.

Comment: My Domain is a much better approach. In tandem with My Domain you can create a Force.com Site and create hosts a externally visible simple VF page that is a blank page that is used instead of a random blank page on internet. That would be 100% on platform.

Comment: You would probably be better off making your own blank page though. Just in case that page doesn't stay blank.  `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>`

Comment: Has anyone actually created a VF page with My Domain and used this in the right side of the login screen? I seem to run into issues with it not loading due to an iframe sandboxing issue - other sites work fine. Is this a valid answer that someone can validate?
-Edit: Logging in the following morning and it appears to now work, so I can confirm that this is a valid approach

Answer (score 4):

If you are using chrome, you can make a chrome extension to do this. Firefox and I think Safari also allow you to make extensions.

My extension widens the login inputs, but making the advertising div invisible should be pretty easy also.

Make a manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 1,

  "name": "Modify CSS and HTML",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Modifies Salesforce Login Pages",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "Your_Icon.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [{
    "css": ["styles.css"],
    "matches": ["https://test.salesforce.com/*","https://login.salesforce.com/*"]
  }]

}
```

CSS:

```
#right {
    display: none!important;
    /*you could also try visibility:hidden!important;*/
}
```

Add an icon (19x19 px), put these into a folder and zip it.

Then open your extensions folder in chrome and drag the zip onto the extensions area. Chrome will recognise it and install it.

For the full login tweak example, check it out on github [here](https://github.com/rapsacnz/SFLoginTweak)

Comment: What about blocking the image load altogether? For instance it may be a bandwidth issue.

Comment: Novel approach :)

I admin this but it's for another agency.  I cannot ask them install a plug-in on their browsers.  It's not as much as a bandwidth issue as much as it's a branding/usability issue.  I don't need users getting spammed with stuff unnecessarily.  It looks tacky.  Many (all) of them don't care about IQ or Dreamforce or Beniof.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, blocking the load is probably a good approach. Once you have the extension up and running, you can do anything you like :)

Comment: used stylebot and the CSS and voila ads went away. Thank you very much. The new dreamforce ad was hard to look at

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to customize the right side section, see bullet #6 in [Customize Your Login Page with Your Brand](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_name_login_branding.htm&language=en_US):

> 6. Enter the URL of the file to be included in the right-side iFrame on
>      the login page. The content in the right-side iFrame can resize to
>      fill about 50% of the page. Your content must be hosted at a URL that
>      uses SSL encryption and the https:// prefix. To build your own custom
>      right-side iFrame content page using responsive web design, use the
>      [My Domain Sample](https://github.com/salesforceidentity/MyDomain-Sample) template. Example:
>      https://c.salesforce.com/login-messages/promos.html

In our SSO setup users do not have to enter any passwords, and they are not maintained in Salesforce - when user is clicking on the SF bookmark for our domain (e.g. https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com) they are logged in automatically when they are on domain, or being asked for a domain user login password served from the corporate identity provider website. Also, when they click on the hyperlink (e.g. https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/SFrecordID) they are logged in as above and redirected to the record page.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote this article that goes through all the steps to set up a site and make it fit for showing on the right side of the salesforce login page:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/step-by-step-instructions-hosting-setting-up-login-page-guy-clairbois

Might be useful for anyone looking for a solution for this.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.